# bash : java : command not found (Fedora)

Tags: java, bash, terminal, version

On Fedora I installed (or at least tried to install) JDK-18. I rebooted my laptop and wanted to check if it succeeded. I used *java --version*, but it said *bash : java : command not found*.

Comment: Is the Java bin directory in your $PATH?   That;'s basic Linux stuff - to run something it must be added to the lookup path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well all that I will write is subjective. It all depends upon how did you install java in Fedora. If you downloaded the jdk distribution and unzipped it to some folder. Then in your .bashrc, you need to provide the path where the binaries are available

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/java/installation/folder/bin

You can also look at sdkman
https://sdkman.io/

This is a nice tool to manage your JDK(s) regardless of Linux distribution you are using. (disclaimer: I have no affiliation with sdkman - i find this tool very helpful)